# Custom ribbon tab in excel 2010 does not show up after installation of vsto c#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2010

I have created a excel 2010 template project wherein I have added a custom ribbon for excel. 
When I try running the project from visual studio, the custom ribbon along with button does show up but after publishing the project and installing the published .VSTO file, the ribbon does not show up when I try opening normal excel file.

I am using VS 2012.

Can anyone help me find out why the ribbon does not show in excel after installation of .VSTO?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34588769/1295010 - check if it is your case

Comment: Thanks Alex for response. I am Win7 OS and don't think there is a preview for excel file in explorer. I can see the Add-In while running the project from VS but when I install it on my local machine and try to open even a blank or new excel file, the add-in does not show up.

Comment: Did you install it on different machine? Maybe something is wrong with installation? Check if you have it in the list of your COM-addins, enabled. And enable "Show add-in user interface error". BTW, windows 7 can have preview for files, too. It is just disabled by default.